# Drag and Drop Problems

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I'm developing an android app which the user can simply drag an icon around the screen freely, however, when i drag my icon(imageview) to the bottom or to the right, it's getting smaller and smaller as i drag (bottom or to right)..

I wanted to keep my icon size whenever i drag it wherever around my screen.

Please help. I'm tring to solve this for days now.. Thank you.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int windowwidth;
int windowheight;
ImageView ce;

private android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams ;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    windowwidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    windowheight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

    System.out.println("width" +windowwidth);
    System.out.println("height" +windowheight);

    ce = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagecenter);
    ce.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) ce.getLayoutParams();

            switch(event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                    int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();

                    System.out.println("value of x" +x_cord);
                    System.out.println("value of y" +y_cord);

                    if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
                        x_cord = windowwidth;
                    }
                    if (y_cord > windowheight) {
                        y_cord = windowheight;
                    }
                    layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord-25;
                    layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord-25;
                    ce.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    break;
                default: break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
} }
```

XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg2"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagecenter"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/imagec" /></RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I don't have an answer for this.  But it sounds like the bounds of the image are going outside the canvas, so the system is shrinking the image to make it fit.

Comment: it might not be a straight answer but you showed me the larger picture on my problem @durbnpoisn thank you!

Comment: Yeah, that's all I could really provide.  Because I don't know how to solve that problem.  Hope it at least steers you the right way.

Comment: i'm tinkering on 
`layoutParams.leftMargin
 layoutParams.rightMargin 
 layoutParams.topMargin
 layoutParams.bottomMargin` 

just couldn't get the right coordinates. cheers!